# Does gaining an extra domain increase a wizard's spell slots?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, wizard, prestige-class, domains

*Complete Divine* on Extra Domains says that when a creature that casts arcane spells gains a domain then

> If she is a spellcaster who keeps a spellbook as a wizard does, then she must find or purchase a scroll of that spell and pay the usual price to scribe the spell into her spellbook. In cases where the spell is only divine the wizard may scribe a divine scroll into his book. **The wizard then may memorize one domain spell of each level each day.** (20)

(Readers, try not to fixate on the pre-*Third Edition* term *memorize*; assume *Complete Divine* means *prepare*.) While *Complete Divine* provides examples of how an extra domain affects the casting ability of, respectively,  a paladin, a cleric, then a sorcerer, it doesn't provide an example of how an extra domain affects the casting of a wizard.

Is this *one domain spell of each level each day* in addition to the wizard's normal spell allotment—therefore, essentially, an extra spell slot per day at each spell level above 0 but that's only capable of holding a domain spell—, or does that phrase limit the wizard's spell preparation options but leaves unchanged the wizard's spell slots? Or is there another altogether different way to read this that I'm overlooking?

An example: Travaran is a human diviner 7/divine oracle 6. A level 1 class feature of the prestige class divine oracle (*CD* 34–6) grants him access to the domain Oracle (*Spell Compendium* 277–8) that has as its 1st-level domain spell the 1st-level normally-Sor/Wiz spell [*identify*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsHtoL.html#identify) [div] (*Player's Handbook* 243).

Until he gained that first level of the prestige class divine oracle, Travaran—who already had the spell *identify* in his spellbook—could prepare and cast as many times as he wanted the *identify* spell (within the limits of his spell slots and casting ability, of course). After taking that one level of divine oracle and gaining access to the domain Oracle, though, can he now, for example, prepare an additional *identify* spell at each of his spell levels 1st through 7th? Or can he now, for example, prepare the *identify* spell only *once* at each of his spell levels 1st through 7th? Or, y'know, something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No additional spell slots are gained.

Just before the text cited in the question is the following (emphasis mine):

> If  she  memorizes  spells  like  a  druid,  paladin,  or  ranger,  then  she  can  simply  choose  to  memorize  one  of  that  domain’s  spells  **instead  of  one  of  her  usual  spells**,  but  never  more  than  one  domain  spell  of  each  level.

While it may be tempting to treat the "if ..." sentences of this paragraph as dependent on each other (i.e. to treat them as "however, if ..."), such an interpretation would imply that only non-casters would gain the domain power, which is contradicted by the examples given in the following paragraphs. Therefore, the "if ..." sentences are all independent (i.e. should be treated as "furthermore, if ..."). So the "if ..." about memorized spells applies in this case, and Travaran can only prepare his domain spells in place of his usual spells.

Because *identify* was already on Travaran's spell list before he gained the domain, he can continue to prepare it normally (i.e. as many instances as he wants across as many spell slots of at least 1st level as he wants).

If his base class were instead some wizard-analogue that didn't have *identify* on its class list, the implications of the "never more than one domain spell of each level" language would be a little unclear on whether he could allocate one spell slot of each level to *identify* (i.e. one spell slot of each level he can prepare) or only one spell slot total (i.e. one spell slot of each level of spell granted by the domain). My inclination would be to rule for the former (up to 7 instances of *identify* prepared, if he's willing to throw a slot per level at it).

Comment: The problem is that the phrasing of this text is that "If she memorises spells like a druid, paladin, or ranger, then X. If she keeps a spellbook like a wizard, then Y. If she is a spontaneous caster, then Z." The logical parsing is that these are mutually exclusive sections, because a wizard doesn't memorise spells like a druid, paladin, or ranger (or a sorcerer or favoured soul). I agree that it is almost certainly the intention that a wizard doesn't get more spells per day, since the other options are explicit that does not happen, it's just ambiguously written in the wizard's case.

Comment: I parse it as two sections, one with a sub-section, rather than as three sections (i.e. with an implied "furthermore" before the bit about spellbooks), but that's possible too. That said, it's probably not a good idea to get into "well, the rule doesn't technically say I *don't* get this extra power..."; that way madness lies.

Comment: Maybe the answer should include that dissection? My reading is as Carcer suggests, but you make a good point with your alternative.